# The volume factor of a partition function

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, partition-function, volume

Something that has bugged me for years but I've never taken the time to ask.

Given an ideal gas in a box of volume $V$ and $N$ molecules of gas.

The states of the systems is all the coordinates and momenta of all the molecules. Let's assume our box is 3-dimensional.

Then there are 3 coordinates for each molecule, and 3 momenta for each molecule.

And so which this continuous system, the partition function is an integral over phase space.

This is all clear to me with one particle, but the factor of $V^N$ one gets from the partition function for $N$ particles confuses me a great deal.

Why is it necessary that the partition function have multiple factors of $V$? What is this accounting for? That EACH particle has free reign over the entirety of the box?

This misunderstanding stems from a confusion about what the partition function IS. Via the Gibbs entropy/Lagrange multiplier derivation, I can find an expression for it... but what IS it? Just a function of thermodynamic quantities?

Comment: "...EACH particle has free reign over the entirety of the box?" If they are non-interacting particle subject to no potential field, then yes, why wouldn't they? In this free particle case there is no reason for the particle to be in any one given position relative to any other given position.

Answer (score 1):

Factor $V^N$ is just a normalization factor... and it does not always have such a simple form. Let us consider microcanonical distribution for $N$ particles:
$$
\rho(\mathbf{p},\mathbf{q})= Z^{-1}\exp\left[-\beta H(\mathbf{p},\mathbf{q})\right]
$$
The partition function $Z$ is then found from the normalization condition
$$
\int d^{3N}\mathbf{p}\int d^{3N}\mathbf{q}\rho(\mathbf{p},\mathbf{q})=1\\
\Rightarrow
Z = \int d^{3N}\mathbf{p}\int d^{3N}\mathbf{q}\exp\left[-\beta H(\mathbf{p},\mathbf{q})\right]
$$
If we now consider **non-interacting particles**,
$$
H(\mathbf{p}, \mathbf{q})=T(\mathbf{p})=\sum_{i=1}^{3N}\frac{p_i^2}{2m}
$$
then the integration over coordinates can be readily carried out and gives the volume
$$
Z = V^N\int d^{3N}\mathbf{p}\exp\left[-\beta T(\mathbf{p})\right],
V=\iiint dq_1 dq_2 dq_3
$$
(One can trivially carry out the remaining [Gaussian integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral).)

However, if we are dealing with a **gas of interacting particles**, the integration is not that simple. In case of a simple potential term with
$$
H(\mathbf{p}, \mathbf{q})=T(\mathbf{p})+U(\mathbf{q})
$$
we would have
$$
Z = \int d^{3N}\mathbf{p}\exp\left[\beta T(\mathbf{p})\right]
\int d^{3N}\mathbf{q}\exp\left[\beta U(\mathbf{q})\right],
$$
where the first integral can be again easily dealt with using Gaussian integration, whereas the second integral is known as configuration integral, and plays the central role in the [cluster expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_expansion).

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that the position and momentum of the particles were not continous but rather quantized to discrete values (we can always coarse grain and refine the graining to obtain a better description of the system). Lets say we're looking at volume pieces of size $a$ and need $M$ of them to fill the whole volume.
The partition function can be defined as the normalization factor of the Boltzmann statistic. If you have a system in thermal equilibrium with a bath at temperature $T$, the ratio between the probabilities of the system being in state $A$ or $B$ is given by the Boltzmann distribution

$$ \frac{P(A)}{P(B)} =  \frac{e^{- \beta E_A}}{e^{-\beta E_B}}$$

The probability itself is hence proportional to the Boltzmann factor

$$ P(A) = \frac{ e^{-\beta \, E_{A}}}{Z} $$

where the partition function $Z$ can be calculated via a sum over all possible states of the system (since probabilities need to sum to one).

$$ Z = \sum_{states} \, e^{-\beta \, E_{state}} \\
= \sum_{\vec{x_1},\vec{x_2},...,\vec{x_N}} \, \sum_{\vec{p_1},...} e^{-\beta \, \sum_i \frac{\vec{p_i}^2}{2m}}  = M^{N} \, \sum_{\vec{p_1},...} e^{-\beta \, \sum_i \frac{\vec{p_i}^2}{2m}}$$

Where the last step was possible because the energy of the particles doesn't depend on the position. Note that in our setting the partition function is dimensionless. We got a factor of $M^N$ which is equivalent to the volume.

Comment: I would emphasize that in statistical mechanics we say that ALL microstates fulfilling a certain macrostate have the same probability (microcanonical formulation) or the probability determined by a Boltzmann factor (canonical formulation). You average the observables of the system over a VERY long time so that each possible state is realised many times - proportionally to the probability. This is the ergodic principle that is fundamental to understanding thermodynamics (and why it sometimes fails).

Comment: You could also comment on the N! (N factorial) factor coming from the indistinguishability of the particles. This means that you don't really have to assume that it's probable that the particle will travel a large distance to the other part of the container.